# Exception Check with 0 argument(s): Upload of file was successful, but error occurred while setting the permissions and/or timestamp.**

Tags: windows, winscp, winscp-net

I have this Code:

```
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"


$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
  Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
  HostName = "[Windows Server host]"
  UserName = "[username]"
  Password = "[password]"
  SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 1024..."
}


# Optionally, set the "Ignore permission errors" option
$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("SftpIgnorePermErrors", "1")
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
  # Connect
  $session.Open($sessionOptions)

  # Upload
  $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
  $transferOptions.PreserveTimestamp = $False  # Disable preserving timestamps
  $transferOptions.FilePermissions = $Null    # Disable setting permissions

  $session.PutFiles("path\*.xlsx", "/destination/").Check()
  
    }
finally
{
  # Disconnect, clean up
  $session.Dispose()
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Exception calling "Check" with "0" argument(s): "**Upload of file 'filename.xlsx' was 
successful, but error occurred while 
setting the permissions and/or timestamp.**
If the problem persists, turn off setting permissions or preserving timestamp. Alternatively 
you can turn on 'Ignore permission errors' option.
The server does not support the operation.
Error code: 8
Error message from server: SSHServerAPI.SFTP.fxp_attrs"
At path\report.ps1:28 char:7
+       $session.PutFiles("path ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SessionRemoteException
```

Please help. I have set ReserveTimestamp to $False and FilePermissions to Null, but I'm still getting this error. I don't know if I set correctly or maybe is something else.